# Create asymmetric key from a passphrase

Tags: c#, encryption-asymmetric

I want to allow users on my site to create an asymmetric private & public key so they can:

- upload the public key to the site so my web application can encrypt
  files they upload
- download files and decrypt them using a local
  application and the private key

My issue is that if the users machine dies then they will most likely loose their private key.

My concept is that the application the users download to pull the files from the site will also allow them to generate the keys for use on the site.

So my question is, Is it possible to create an asymmetric private/public key pair based on a passphrase? This would allow the user to regenerate the private key if required.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You might want to change the title to say "asymmetric" if that's what you're really looking for.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do exactly what you are asking is:

1. Define a security level N, the larger the more secure but slower this process will be.
2. Generate a "salt" and associate it with the user's id.
3. Since RSA key generation requires a secure random number generator, use the user's password and salt with PBKDF2, starting at iteration N, to generate secure random data.

This process should deterministically generate a public/private RSA key pair. However, the reasons not to do this are:

- It was cooked up by me and, AFAIK, this post is the first time this process will be publicly vetted.
- It is not known to me if PBKDF2 actually works as a secure random number generator for use with RSA.
- It may or may not be true the PBKDF2 is guaranteed to generate a data from which a public/private RSA key pair will originate.
- In practice, while this does work, it takes a very long time and the time it takes is based on the user's password, which is a user experience and security exposure point that needs considered.

A better way to accomplish what you are trying to do is:

1. Define a security level N, the larger the more secure but slower this process will be.
2. Generate a "salt" and associate it with the user's id.
3. Generate an RSA public / private key pair.
4. Iterate PBKDF2 N times to create a symmetric key based on the user's password and salt.
5. Use a symmetric encryption algorithm to encrypt the private key.
6. Upload the unencrypted public key and encrypted private key to the server.

This is better because:

- All processes listed above are, AFAIK, standard and vetted.
- Generation of public / private keys (time consuming) only occurs once while setting up the user's account.
- Accessing the keys always occurs in a fixed amount of time.

This solves your problem:

- Since the server only has the encrypted private key it cannot decrypt the user's data.
- If the client machine dies the server can re-issue the private key.

Of course there are the obvious warnings like if the user forgets their password all their data is locked until public knowledge on how to crack RSA is available or a billion years of current computing power is put to the task of breaking their password ;-) (depending on N and key size of course). Also, the salt is important to prevent dictionary attacks.

Answer (score 0):

What the fields are for your algorithm (e.g. RSA http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters.aspx) are more or less up to you.  You could easily create an algorithm to generate D and P from some string (calculating the other RSA fields from those).  I'd really recommend you wouldn't pick one from an answer on StackOverflow though (that would simply give someone who wanted to get at your data something easy to try).

The reason algorithms like RSA are hard to break is the amount of effort that goes into reverse engineering the private/public key based on the encrypted data.  If you introduce a "shortcut" like a reproducible generation algorithm based on a passphrase, the security of your system now depends on how well the passphrase is kept secret, not the encryption algorithm itself.

The same is true for the private key; which is why many organizations don't store the private key on hard drives and store them on secure external devices protected by a password or some biometric information.

I'd recommend you *do not* generate keys from a passphrase and simply use recommended practices for storing and protecting your private key.

Comment: I completely understand your point. However the two options available to me as per my example is to either get the user to generate the keys and back them up themselves securely or recreate the key(s) with something only they know. I personally don't want to know their password that is why I want them to send me a public key not a password.

Comment: I'm not clear why anyone would find that useful?  Ignoring the inherent security holes with it, why would someone upload unencrypted files that they'd have to decrypt when they download them?  Why would then not just encrypt the data, *then* upload it?  Much less hassles for them--plus more secure.

Comment: Sorry I should have stated in my question that the local app would also upload file, the server side encryption is just in case users wanted to upload files away from their 'home' machine.

Comment: The issue I have is still if a users 'home' machine dies they then have no way to recover the data they uploaded.

Comment: Sure, but this is the problem that certificates solves.  I *get* you want to handle lost certificates--but, that's really the client's problem.  If you want then to *buy in* to asymmetric encryption for security, they should buy into a fully secure implementation, not one with a gaping security hole.